# AppDelegate multiple nitifications

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have this line of code :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(savingAll),
                                       name: Notification.Name("AppMinimilised"),
                                       object: nil)
```

and a Function

```
func savingAll(){
    print("saving")
}
```

however, for some magical reason, when the app closes, i get the print(and other things included in the function) multiple times!

What i noticed is, when i open the view with that code first time and minimised the app, i only get this print once
however if i leave this view and come back to it, and minimalise again, i will get another one.
any explanations?

Comment: Where you put this observe line ?

Comment: By observe line, do you mean where do I register for notifications?

Comment: yes, ...............

Comment: In the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you un register

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

}
```

//

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(savingAll), name:Notification.Name("AppMinimilised"), object: nil)

}
```

Comment: So i tested it, and i got this error                   Argument labels '(_:, selector:, _:, object:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: see edit ......... also don't forget to remove old observe in viewDidLoad

Comment: Edit? What do you mean ? Sorry super new to this